# Jhipster deployment to aws failing - No Solution Stack named '64bit Amazon Linux 2015.03 v1.4.1 running Tomcat 8 Java 8' found

Tags: jhipster

I am trying to deploy my application built using JHipster on AWS by following the steps mentioned in this document - http://jhipster.github.io/aws.html

It fails. This is what I see printed on my command prompt.

Create S3 bucket

Bucket already exists

Upload WAR to S3

War uploaded successful

Create database

Database created successful

Waiting for database (This may take several minutes)
Database available at jdbc:mysql://UrlToDb:3306/

Create/Update application

**x No Solution Stack named '64bit Amazon Linux 2015.03 v1.4.1 running Tomcat 8 
Java 8' found.**

Can someone please help me with resolving the problem here.

Thanks in advance,
Ankit

Answer (score 0):

The issue should be fixed in the new jhipster release, check the following bug https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues/789#issuecomment-133468642